# Using Regex to review a Text File in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file-io

What I am trying to accomplish here is basically have Reg ex return the match I want based on the pattern from a text file that Python has created and written too.

Currently I am getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` error and I am not sure why. If I need more information let me know.

```
   #Opens Temp file 
TrueURL = open("TrueURL_tmp.txt","w+")

#Reviews Data grabbed from BeautifulSoup and write urls to file
for link in g_data:
    TrueURL.write(link.get("href") + '\n')

#Creates Regex Pattern for TrueURL_tmp
pattern = re.compile(r'thread/.*/*apple|thread/.*/*potato')
search_pattern = re.search(pattern, str(TrueURL))

#Uses Regex Pattern against TrueURL_tmp file.
for url in search_pattern:
    print (url)


#Closes and deletes file    
TrueURL.close() 
os.remove("TrueURL_tmp.txt")
```

Comment: Hi Padraic, thanks for getting back to me so quickly. Beside that is there anything I am doing anything wrong with using Regex to looking into the file?'

Comment: why are you using a file at all?

Comment: Hi Padraic, the reason why I wanted to do it to a file is because originally I was not able to do regex on a list.

Comment: If you want to check for a match then just do it in the loop as per the last part of my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search is returning no match because you are doing it on the `str` representation of the `file object` not the actual file content.

You are basically searching something like:

```
<open file 'TrueURL_tmp.txt', mode 'w+' at 0x7f2d86522390>
```

If you want to search the file content, close the file so the content is definitely written, then reopen and read the lines or maybe just search in the loop `for link in g_data:`

If you actually want to write to  temporary file then use a tempfile:

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
with  TemporaryFile() as f:
    for link in g_data:
        f.write(link.get("href") + '\n')
    f.seek(0)
    #Creates Regex Pattern for TrueURL_tmp
    pattern = re.compile(r'thread/.*/*apple|thread/.*/*potato')
    search_pattern = re.search(pattern, f.read())
```

`search_pattern` is a `_sre.SRE_Match object` so you would call group i,e  `print(search_pattern.group())` or maybe you want to use findAll.

```
 search_pattern = re.findall(pattern, f.read())

 for url in search_pattern:
     print (url)
```

I still think doing the search before you write anything might be the best  approach and maybe not writing at all but I am not fully sure what it is you actually want to do because I don't see how the file fits into what you are doing, concatenating to a string would achieve the same.

```
 pattern = re.compile(r'thread/.*/*apple|thread/.*/*potato')
 for link in g_data:
        match = pattern.search(link.get("href"))
        if match:
           print(match.group())
```

Comment: This does not provide a solution, just an explanation of the error.

Comment: @Kwarrtz, the error is pretty important to understanding the problem, I also provide how to get the code working so not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have found to answer my original question with, although Padraic way is correct and less painful process.

```
 with  TemporaryFile() as f:
    for link in g_data:
        f.write(bytes(link.get("href") + '\n', 'UTF-8'))
    f.seek(0)
    #Creates Regex Pattern for TrueURL_tmp
    pattern = re.compile(r'thread/.*/*apple|thread/.*/*potato')
    read = f.read()
    search_pattern = re.findall(pattern,read)
    #Uses Regex Pattern against TrueURL_tmp file.
    for url in search_pattern:
        print (url.decode('utf-8'))
```